# What is a good way to think of Caratheodory Hahn theorem intuitively?

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading the theorem in Royden's book on Caratheodory Hahn theorem. After reading it for like 10 times, I still do not quite understand it. Can anyone please offer some intuition?

Comment: Can you write down what the theorem says? Some theorems of measure theory and real analysis are quite technical, are might be void of intuition.

Comment: check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem)

Comment: Well, that qualifies (in my opinion) as being a bit too technical. Did you read the motivation in the link you gave? The theorem essentially says how to obtain a measure from a rather simple family of objects that might be more intuitive: in $\Bbb R^n$ is says that Lebesgue measure is essentially constructed from the rule that $\mu[a,b) = b-a$. Rings of sets and premeasures are manageable, while $\sigma$-rings are quite unmanageabñe. A remedy to this is the use of Dynkin systems. Check, for example, the excellent exposition of René Schilling in "Measures, Integrals and Martingales."

Comment: I have read my book and the page many times, but still feel really lost. What is all this really about....

Comment: Keep on reading. Sometimes you'll have to read things more than once to get them. Perhaps you can skip it and return to it when you have seen more examples. See what suits you.

Comment: The Wikipedia page says that "The Carathéodory's extension theorem states that[2] there exists a measure μ′: σ(R) → [0, + ∞] such that μ′ is an extension of μ." What does extension mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40033/discussion-between-user1559897-and-pedro-tamaroff).